# GTK: How can the size of a TextView be set manually?

Tags: python, xml, pygtk, glade

I am reworking a GUI from scratch using Glade + Python. It was previously done in Tkinter and I could set the height and width of several consoles.

Now, in GTK (newbie) I can't find a proper solution to this: specify a size to the TextView. I imagine it is done by nesting it in a block that sets the size. What's my best option?

Here's my case: http://pastebin.com/dx07HZnC

And a preview: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=24e83d2
As you can see the textView widgets are very short.

Comment: You can call the `set_size_request()` method on the text view. I'm not sure how that translates to a glade project, but that's what you'd normally do in PyGTK.

Comment: Can you describe how this is supposed to act uppon resize/fullscreen? It is hard to give an advice if the desired behaviour is not specified.

Comment: Since I'm new to GTK and Python, for the moment I'd not let the user resize the window. I'll see later how to handle it...

Answer (score 3):

PyGTK2

```
textview = gtk.TextView()
textview.set_size_request(300,200) # W x H
textview.show()
window.add(textview)
```

Answer (score -2):

I can't see your case, but I think that I can help you:

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')

import gtk
import pango

class MyGUI:

def __init__( self, title):
     self.window = gtk.Window()
     self.title = title
     self.window.set_title("Title")
     self.window.set_size_request(260, 300)  ***where 260 is Width and 300 is Height***
     self.window.connect( "destroy", self.destroy)
     self.create_interior()
     self.window.show_all()

 def create_interior( self):
     self.mainbox = gtk.VBox()
     self.window.add( self.mainbox)
     # the textview
     self.textview = gtk.TextView()
     self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
     self.mainbox.pack_start( self.textview)
     self.textview.show()
     h_tag = self.textbuffer.create_tag( "h", size_points=16, weight=10)
     position = self.textbuffer.get_end_iter()
     self.textbuffer.insert( position, "Text...")

     self.mainbox.show()

def main( self):
    gtk.main()

def destroy( self, w):
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MyGUI( "TextView example.")
    m.main()
```