# Is there a way to set the dimensions of a TextView widget in a GTK window, which already contains few other widgets using fixed containers?

Tags: c, textview, gtk, gtk3

I am writing a GTK-3 application, in which I have a few buttons, and a TreeView model. I have added all these widgets to the main GTK window using fixed containers. Now I want to have a fixed portion of the window where I can enter multi-line texts. To do this I used TextView widget, and again added it to the main window using the fixed container. Now my problem is that when I am writing my application this way, I do get a TextView widget on screen (with the text on it which I had set using `gtk_text_buffer_insert()`), but the dimensions of this Textview is just as much as is required to fit the text which is already there. And if I enter more text, then the size of Textview just increases.

[image]

As you can see, the dimension of the TextView widget here is just as much as the width of the text.

Instead of this I want some way using which I can fix the dimensions of TextView, so that no matter how much text is there, a minimum amount of space on the window is dedicated to it, and the TextView is visible there. Also I want that if more text is inserted(than can fit) into the textView, then it should just be a accessible using a scroll bar. How to do this?

I found an answer to a similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48339773/9244482, but it's with respect to python. I checked the GTK-3.20 documentation and cannot find an equivalent of `textview.set_size_request ()` function which is suggested in that answer. I did found a function named `gtk_text_view_set_border_window_size ()` in the documentation, but it just pads the TextView widget with a border, and does not sets the size of TextView itself. I also found an answer on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/GTK/comments/1229qdi/comment/jdsozjw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3, suggesting to use "height/width-request property", but I am unable to find this for TextView in GTK-3.20 documentation.

So, how can I exactly fix the dimensions of TextView in GTK using C?

Answer (score 1):

set-size-request is a generic operation on a widget:

```
gtk_widget_set_size_request (widget, width, height);
```

This will limit the size of a text-view to the specified value in pixels.
Pass a width or height of -1 if you want no particular limit.

But it sounds like you want:

```
gtk_widget_set_hexpand (widget, TRUE);
gtk_widget_set_vexpand (widget, TRUE);
```

And if you want a scrollbar, it needs to be packed into a scrolled window.

Comment: Thanks for helping out!, using ```gtk_widget_set_size_request ()``` worked with what I actually wanted. But, what exactly ```gtk_widget_set_hexpand ()``` and ```gtk_widget_set_vexpand ()``` do. I just read the documentation where it states that "Call this function to set the expand flag if you would like your widget to become larger horizontally when the window has extra room." So I think if I set it with FALSE for my textview, then on adding extra text, textview shouldn't expand, right? But it is still expanding even if I set it to FALSE.

Comment: @Shobhit Also set the expand flags to false on the scrolled window container if you don't want any expansion at all.  It would be helpful to see your code.